# Photoshop: Convert image with alpha channel to transparency?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, transparency

I have a .dds texture which has R, G, B, and Alpha channels. The Alpha channel stores the transparency info. I have this file open in Photoshop.

I want to convert this to a .png file.

What's the best way to go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doubleclick on background layer to make it floating. Load the alpha channel as a selection (select menu or from channels palette). Invert selection hit delete.

If your image was premultiplied by color then defringe or remove black white matte but if it was not you dont need to do thism

Comment: I see. The image now appears faded - I'm guessing that means it was premultiplied by a color. I then removed white matte. It worked perfectly.

Comment: @Brent if you liked the answer enough to accept it, you should upvote it too.  Upvotes are what separate the good from the bad here and also reward the user for their effort.

Comment: @Manly thanks for the tip. Upvoted it and your comment!